# Can the size of the icon that shows programs are grouped be increased?

Tags: kubuntu, icons, taskbar

Can the size of the icon in the taskbar that shows programs are grouped be increased?

[image: Icon for app which is grouped in taskbar]

The Icon which is little green circle with plus in it.